# MacOS TimeMachine sparsebundle corrupt

Tags: backup, time-machine, disk-utility, mount, sparsebundle

I'm somewhat pissed off with my almost 6TB TM backups that have become unusable, particularly after Apple had to replace my MBP (failed mobo).

TM running on a Synology NAS.

What I get now from 1st aid is this (same from fsck):

```
Checking file system and repairing if necessary and if possible.
Volume is already unmounted.
Performing fsck_apfs -y -x /dev/rdisk3s1
Checking the container superblock.
Checking the checkpoint with transaction ID 2116640.
Checking the space manager.
Checking the space manager free queue trees.
Checking the object map.
Checking volume /dev/rdisk3s1.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
The volume Backups of MacBook Pro PAN was formatted by newfs_apfs 
(1933.61.1) and last modified by apfs_kext (2142.101.3).

Checking the object map.
error: (oid 0xc26f758) om: btn: invalid o_oid (0x406)
error: (oid 0xc26f758) om: btn: invalid o_subtype (0xe, expected 0xb)
error: (oid 0xc26f758) om: btn: invalid o_type (0x3, expected 0x40000003)
Object map is invalid.

The volume /dev/rdisk3s1 was found to be corrupt and cannot be repaired.

Verifying allocated space.
The volume /dev/rdisk3s1 could not be verified completely.
File system check exit code is 8.

Restoring the original state found as unmounted.

File system verify or repair failed. : (-69845)

Operation failed…
```

Strangely enough, I previously could do a `hdiutil attach` and see the partitions inside, I've just restarted, and now always get a `hdiutil: attach failed - Resource temporarily unavailable` message, although with the exact same command as before?

Any comment/idea appreciated !

Comment: This shouldn't make any difference, but did you restart the Synology?

Comment: Sure I did... TM on NAS is unsupported, and I'm gonna drop TM, NAS or NOT, it's a piece of junk, not providing any support, despite the fact that some data is definitely recoverable, is not acceptable in a professional context.

Comment: And in a "professional context", of course it's not your only backup.

Comment: I do, but not of everything… and not as up-to-date as TM… but that doesn’t change the fact that TM can’t be called “professional grade”, which is a pity !

Comment: My personal opinion is I'm not sure Apple ever called TM "professional grade".  BTW, what does "professional grade" mean?

Comment: Not sure this is the right place to debate about this… if you don’t have any valuable input regarding the original question/issue, let’s stop here.